# How can I invoke javascript functions with c# with Gekofx Browser

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I am using the Gekofx browser because my html files don't work with the default webbrowser control.

So far I was using *ObjectForScripting* to call javascript code from my C# project. But I was not able to call anything with the Gekofx browser.

I just want to send some data to my html file and display it with the Gekofx browser. Is it possible at all?

For contemplation here is my code:

```
GeckoWebBrowser myBrowser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        String path = @"C:\tools\xulrunner\xulrunner-sdk\bin";

        Console.WriteLine("Path: " + path);

        Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(path);

        myBrowser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
        myBrowser.Parent = this;
        myBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void btn_go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // like the normal browsers
        myBrowser.Navigate(tbx_link.Text);
    }

    private void btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // getting the link to my own html file
        String path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Webpage");
        path += "\\Webpage.html";myBrowser.Navigate(path);

    }
```

I hope you understand what I mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always invoke javascript like this:

```
mybrowser.Navigate("javascript:YourJavascriptFunction('yourArgument1', 'youArgument2')");
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. But I guess in my code is something wrong or still incomplete. Because the line doesn't do anything. Here is my javascript code: `<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function test(message) 
   { 
  alert(message); 
   }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>` Is there something left to do?

Comment: And you tested it with mybrowser.Navigate("javascript:test('Test')");?

Comment: Yes exactly. There is no feedback. BUT it works after implementing following code section into my `btn_test_Click`: `myBrowser.Navigate(path);
            MessageBox.Show("Stop!");
            myBrowser.Navigate("javascript:test('Test')");` 
I don't no why but it works. Can you possibly explain me why?

Comment: Probably because the browser needs some time to navigate to the page before you can continue. But glad to see it works! Remember to check the answer if you accept it so others know this method works ;)

Comment: Yes this is the mistake. I put it on a previous position and now it works fine. Thank you very much for your simple but very very useful help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @jordy's answer above, call:

```
mybrowser.Navigate("javascript:YourJavascriptFunction('yourArgument1', 'youArgument2')");
```

prefferably in the Document complete event handler to allow for the page to first load.

```
 void myBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
         myBrowser.Navigate("javascript:YourJavascriptFunction('yourArgument1', 'youArgument2')");
    }
```